# Building xnu & using it @ Xcode

Tags: xcode, kernel, kernel-extension, xnu

I'm currently developing a driver in osx and i'm having problem using XNU files in my Xcode project. I built XNU according to the instructions here:
http://shantonu.blogspot.co.il/2013/10/building-xnu-for-os-x-109-mavericks.html

It successfully builds.

Should I install it in a specific directory for XCODE to find the library and header files?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For developing kernel extensions to use with regular OSX kernels, you shouldn't be using a self-compiled kernel, but use the Kernel.framework that Apple supplies with Xcode and the bundled OS X SDK. If you're using Xcode for your build process anyway, the easiest way is to use one of the kext target templates (I/O Kit driver or generic kext) to set up the build system and include the kernel.framework.

If you have an existing Xcode project to which you want to add a kext build, open it and create a new target, then choose one of the kext templates under "system plugin". You get the same choice when you create a new project altogether.

As for choosing between the two templates:

- Generic kext is mainly useful if your userspace application will explicitly load the kext.
- I/O kit kexts can be loaded automatically on device hotplug or on system boot, so they are usually the most useful if your kext doesn't have some kind of userspace trigger.